# Deploy a polymer app on mobile phones

Tags: android, ios, polymer

I would like to know if it is possible to deploy a polymer app on a mobile phone or tablet? But like a real app. You know, with an icon on your phone, you tap on it and it launch the app. It would be mostly for android and iOS phones.

I've started to search for tutorial like this but found nothing really clear, or it was outdated (= for polymer 0.5)

Comment: I am not familiar with it, but it looks like a web framework. If so, you could wrap it in Cordova/Phonegap easily enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  There were quite a lot of talks on Google I/O 2016 on how to.  You have to meet conditions about service works and manifest files. The Polymer team have brought out a command line tool (called Polymer) that helps to create the basis of such an app.  They also have a sample "shop" app that shows you how.